# android 101 - listview inheritance question

Tags: android, inheritance, listview

I have a ListView in my extended ListActivity class.

And then I have the following code to detect my click on the list

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
   Log.i("", ""+l.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

I want to get the data string associated to my click.

1. When I run the code, I get an error with getSelectedItem().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html. 
getSelectedItem() is not method of ListView but it is defined in the superclass AdapterView.
How is that possible? Rolling Eyes

2.
 Also , I'm not sure I understand this line:
android.widget.AdapterView
when it also inherits from   android.view.ViewGroup
isn't that multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can get a Java stack trace via [`adb logcat`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat), [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html), or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse, which will help you pin down your error.
2. That demonstrates an inheritance tree, which is supported by most modern OO languages. `ViewGroup` is the parent of `AdapterView` which is the parent of `AbsListView` which is the parent of `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

1. the easiest way to do this is probably this:

   getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this); //in ListActivity.onCreate

then add this method:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
    getListAdapter().getItem(id); //you may need to cast this to whatever you expect
}
```

2. you can take a look at the inheritance tree - there you can see that no multiple inheritance is involved in this case :)

   - java.lang.Object
   - android.view.View
   - android.view.ViewGroup
   - android.widget.AdapterView
   - android.widget.AbsListView
   - android.widget.ListView